# Obtaining a list of all Java classes used from all JVM's?

Tags: java, linux, classloader

I want to have a list of all the classes that are loaded within multiple threads/JVM's at a certain moment in time.

I know that when you run java with the `-verbose` parameter, you can write it to a file as something like this: `java -verbose:class com.package.Foo > classes-used.txt`

However, I have threads in my main program that use a shell script to start a new jar. I would like to avoid to have to write the `-verbose` parameter in every shell script and I'm wondering if there is any other way to do this on Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the jcmd command that comes with the JDK.  It does not require any special arguments to be past to the JVM upon start.

```
jcmd
```

Will list all of the JVMs that are currently running, along with their pid (process id).

```
jcmd <pid> GC.class_histogram
```

will then list every class that is currently loaded in that JVM, along with a count of how many instances.