# Obtaining a list of all Java classes's location used from all JVM's?

Tags: java, linux, classloader

This question goes a little bit further than my previous question:

[Obtaining a list of all Java classes used from all JVM's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081409/obtaining-a-list-of-all-java-classes-used-from-all-jvms)

Now I need to know the physical location from where those classes are loaded from. I have checked out the jcmd help for other commands but it wasn't useful for me. I also can't find it in jvisualvm, but the information is also not there. Anyone can help me with this?

EDIT:
This is my situation: My company has got different individual java projects (jars) for which we can control whether it starts or stops. We can control this in our own custom build webinterface. Each of such a process gets a process ID (PID) when started, and then runs on the background.

My need: I need a list of all loaded classes by each running PID java process. I already have `jcmd <pid> GC.class_histogram`, but this only contains a list of which classes are loaded. I also want the information where the classes are actually loaded from (which jar, location on file system).

Answer (score 1):

The classes are loaded from `java.lang.ClassLoader's` `loadClass(String name)` method which in turn calls the **`findClass(String name)`** method.Usually,the custom ClassLoader overrides the `findClass` method to retrieve the definition of classes using a specific protocol and location.It may be that classes are loaded from database or from network location,the location of which may be dynamically generated.**So you can never know location of all Java classes.** The best example is *AppletClassLoader*  which loads classes from network stream or from a remote location.

`Bootstrap ClassLoader` - core library package such as `rt.jar` present in JRE lib folder

`Extension ClassLoader` - jar files present in ext folder or as specified in the environment variable for ext

`System ClassLoader` - Application's classpath or as specified in environment variable for classpath or through JVM's startup argument parameter for -cp or -classpath

`CustomClassLader` -accordingly to the classLoader's class loading policy (mostly defined in `findClass()` method)

Comment: From your explanation, I understand that it's not always possible to get to know the location of the used classes. But I would still like to have the cases where it is possible, because 99% of the classes are located in jars located on the filesystem. My company has got a lot of different java projects running, and I need to get the location of the classes per PID.

Comment: Which classes specifically? The classes that are part of the project? All classes in dependency jars that the project has? Perhaps explain why you need this information, that makes it easier to understand what scope of answer you are looking for. Its just really open-ended right now.

Comment: Editing the question is not enough, you'd do that and add the information asked. "I want the location where the classes are coming from, because  ..." - please fill in the dot dot dot.

Comment: Because my company has many different kind of versions for each jar. Each jar also has many connections to many other jars. For logging reasons, my company wants to know which exact classes are loaded from where for overview.